# How to show the dialog of all the messaging options in android?

Tags: android, sms, android-contacts, whatsapp

[image]I am trying to send text `messages` to the selected contacts on the phone using the `SmsManager`  but by default it sends the message using the phone `GSM` message option. My requirement is to show the popup to the user to choose is messaging options such as `WHATSAPP`, `VIBER` etc as shown in the image

here is my code

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage("9844598445", null, "Hello There", null, null);
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);  
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing right now is directly send an SMS through the SDK. If you want to offer the user the option to send it through another installed app, you need to use an Intent:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:1234567890");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
it.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");   
startActivity(it);
```